# For which numbers of dimensions is the Kulkarni-Nomizu product an injective/surjective map?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra

(This question only concerns tensors over finite-$n$-dimensional real vector spaces.)

The [Kulkarni-Nomizu product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kulkarni%E2%80%93Nomizu_product) is a multilinear map from of pairs of symmetric rank-2 tensors to the space of [algebraic curvature tensors](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379504000497). For which dimensions is this map injective?

The set of pairs of symmetric rank-2 tensors has dimension $n(n+1)$. The set of algebraic curvature tensors has dimension $n^2(n-1)/12$. The former is greater for $n<4$, the latter is greater for $n>4$ (so the map cannot be surjective), and they are equal if $n = 4$.

I suspect that for $n < 4$, the Kulkarni-Nomizu product map is surjective but not injective, for $n = 4$ it is bijective, and for $n > 4$ it is injective but not surjective. Is this correct?

Comment: For any symmetric 2-tensor $h$, we have $h \odot 0 = 0 \odot h = 0\odot 0 = 0$, where $\odot$ stands for the Kulkarni-Nomizu product. Therefore, it is never injective.

Comment: @Didier Hmm, good point. Do you know if it’s ever surjective? I guess that could only be possible for $n < 4$.